# InsertionSort using multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, insertion-sort

In my code i recieve in the first line the values n and d. N will be the number of values i want to write and d the number of numbers in each position n.
So in the next n values i introduze d values. The point of this exercise is to use insertion sort but if the first coord is equal it compares the second and if that happens again compares the third and so on. Example:
Input:

```
5 3
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 0
```

Output:

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n,d,aux;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

    n = sc.nextInt();
    d = sc.nextInt();
    int tab [][] = new int[n][d];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
            aux = sc.nextInt();
            tab[i][j] = aux;
        }
    }
    insertionSort(tab,d);
    System.out.println("---");
    for(int u=0;u<tab.length;u++){
        for(int y=0;y<d;y++){
            System.out.print(tab[u][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void insertionSort(int tab[][],int d){
    int i,j;
    int pos = 0;
    int tmp [][] = new int[1][d];
    for(i = 1;i < tab.length;i++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<d;k++)
            tmp[0][k] = tab[i][k];

        for(j = i; j>0 && tmp[0][0] <= tab[j-1][0];j--)
        {
            while(tmp[0][pos] == tab[j-1][pos] && pos+1<d){
                pos++;
                if(tmp[0][pos] < tab[j-1][pos]){
                    pos=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(pos==0){
                for(int k=0;k<d;k++)
                    tab[j][k] = tab[j-1][k];
            }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<d;k++)
            tab[j][k] = tmp[0][k];
        pos = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my output is wrong:

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: where is the code for printing the array? i cant see it

Comment: i'll put it now, i'll edit

Comment: do you know what's wrong?

Comment: the problem is that if they dont need to change, in the end of for cicle it will be changed anyway. But i tried to put one condition too but if one position is changed and the second doesnt need to, it wouldnt change the first position cause the second didnt need change and it wouldnt do the final for if i put that condition there. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for you with recursion, with the code below you can sort your multidimensional binary array, in binary sorted format (I used constant array here, you can add your scanner to get inputs from console):

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int n, d;

    int tab[][] = new int[][] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
    n = 6;
    d = 4;
    System.out.println("---");
    for (int u = 0; u < tab.length; u++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < d; y++)
      {
        System.out.print(tab[u][y] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    insertionSort(tab, n);

    System.out.println("---");
    for (int u = 0; u < tab.length; u++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < d; y++)
      {
        System.out.print(tab[u][y] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void insertionSort(int tab[][], int n)
  {
    doSort(tab, 0, n, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Recurring Method for Insertion Sort in MulitDimentional array.
   * 
   * @param tab mulitidiamentional array.
   * @param rowsStart the rows start index
   * @param rowEnd  the row end index
   * @param column the current column
   */
  public static void doSort(int tab[][], int rowsStart, int rowEnd, int column)
  {
    int totalColumn = tab[0].length;
    for (int j = rowsStart; j < rowEnd; j++)
    {
      for (int k = j + 1; k < rowEnd; k++)
      {
        if (tab[j][column] > tab[k][column])
        {
          for (int l = column; l < totalColumn; l++)
          {
            int t = tab[j][l];
            tab[j][l] = tab[k][l];
            tab[k][l] = t;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    int value = tab[rowsStart][column];
    if (rowEnd - rowsStart > 2)
    {
      for (int i = rowsStart; i < rowEnd; i++)
      {
        if (value != tab[i][column])
        {
          doSort(tab, rowsStart, i, column + 1);
          value = tab[i][column];
          rowsStart = i;
        }
      }
    }
    if (column < totalColumn - 1)
    {
      doSort(tab, rowsStart, rowEnd, column + 1);
    }
  }
```